# Integration of root of quadratic over quadratic

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need help to get a generalized solution for this type equations:

$$ \Gamma(v) = \int\frac{(1-v^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{a^{2}-b^{2}v^{2} }dv $$

NOTE: This is not a homework question. I am in high school and I was reading up some extra material and landed on this from another equation.

Sorry for the bad formatting.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Your formatting is quite OK. For more help, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for $LaTeX$ syntax. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: You may want to consider a trigonometric substitution $v=\sin\varphi$.

Comment: Usually, if you mention the **context** of your question, namely which hat you pulled out this integral rabbit from, it would not only make the question much more **useful** to subsequent readers, but also might very well be easier to solve if someone recognizes the **motivating** question.

Comment: the solution seems to me complicated

Comment: Not too bad, a little tedious. The Weierstrass substitution is useful.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, Yes I have tried to substitute v=sinφ but it did not help. I here is the question:  $$ \Gamma(x) = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{(6sin^2x\)}{a-bcosx }dx $$ where a>b>0

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I have tried substituting using half angle formulas but it results in partial fractions being used and thus giving me an answer in ln but  the answer according to the source does not contain any ln function.

Comment: If you substitute $v=\sin(\theta)$, then you should end up with$$\int\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{a^2-b^2\sin^2(\theta)}d\theta$$You should then be able to split up that using partial fractions. Your answer may be different from the source only in how it is written. The actual function may be exactly the same.

Comment: @RochanAvlur, Avoid using $\Gamma(v)$ which stands for **Gamma function** or **factorial function**.  You've many other choices: e.g. $f(v)$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $v=\sin\theta$ gives $\sqrt{1-v^2}=\cos\theta$, $dv=\cos\theta\,d\theta$ so we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\int\dfrac{\cos^2\theta}{a^2-b^2\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta&=\int\dfrac{1-\sin^2\theta}{a^2-b^2\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta\\
&=\dfrac{1}{b^2}\int\left[1-\dfrac{a^2-b^2}{2a}\left(\frac{1}{a-b\sin\theta}+\frac{1}{a+b\sin\theta} \right)  \right]\,d\theta
\end{eqnarray}

The rational functions of $\sin\theta$ can be completed by the substitution

\begin{equation}
t=\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right),\, d\theta=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2},\,\sin\theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}
\end{equation}

Comment: Note that although it may appear that you need to know the relative values of $a$ and $b$ you actually do not. It's just that you will get one inverse tangent term and one inverse hyperbolic tangent term.

Comment: Thanks you, I did not think of writing the equation as in the 3rd line.